# Guidance to use libjson2csv package

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-import

I'm trying to convert json to csv, it is nested json and for 40 tables I've to convert json to csv dynamically.

so,I've tried to use libjson2csv package found in pypi.org. but i don't know how to use it in pycharm. package link pasted below.

https://pypi.org/project/libjson2csv/

The code i tried in pycharm:
import libjson2csv
libjson2csv.json_2_csv <'F:\2-5-2020\dson.json'>[]

getting below error:
AttributeError: module 'libjson2csv' has no attribute 'csv_2_json'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
usage: python -m libjson2csv.json_2_csv [--m] <json_in_file_path> [<csv_out_file_path>]
```

this means that you should use it in the terminal for example

```
python -m libjson2csv.json_2_csv --m ./some.json ./result.csv
```

if you want to use it in your python code:

```
import os
from pandas import read_csv as read
// first convert your file 
convert = 'python -m libjson2csv.json_2_csv ./some.json test.csv'
os.system(convert)
// then use it 
path = "test.csv"
data = read(path, delimiter=",")

print(data)
```